# AWS' WAF impact on latency?

Tags: aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

I am attempting to add another load balancer on the critical path to my application that will route to a server to perform some lookups and then route to one of many other public ALB based on those lookups. I currently have AWS' WAF setup on my initial ALB, but I would like to add it to all of the public ALBs. I am trying to find if there are any resources regarding latency impact of adding the WAF to two ALBs for the same request. However, I only see ["minimal latency impact"](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/waf/). Has anyone run tests to get some numbers of the impact of adding the WAF?